# Parse json data into variables and submit to a function on each iteration

Tags: php, javascript, json

I created a php script that generates the json response

this is the example of the output:

```
[[],{"idgps_unit":"2","lat":"40","lon":"40","name":"ML350","notes":"Andrew","dt":"2012-10-29 19:43:09","serial":"3602152","speed":"44","odometer":"208.49"},{"idgps_unit":"1","lat":"42","lon":"39","name":"unit1","notes":"fake unit 1","dt":"2012-10-18 18:16:37","serial":"12345","speed":"0","odometer":"0.16"}]
```

This is how I form the response in PHP:

```
   $data[] = array();
    foreach ($list->arrayList as $key => $value) {

        $unit = new Unit();
        $unit = $value;
        //create array for json output
        $data[] = array('idgps_unit' => $unit->idgps_unit, 'lat' => $unit->lat,
            'lon' => $unit->lon, 'name' => $unit->name, 'notes' => $unit->notes,
            'dt' => $unit->dt, 'serial' => $unit->serial, 'speed' => $unit->speed,
            'odometer' => $unit->odometer);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Now, in JS I did this:

```
function getCheckedUnits() {
    jQuery(function($) {    
        $.ajax( {           
            url : "json.php?action=get",
            type : "GET",
            success : function(data) {
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

                ///PARSE VALUES AND SUBMIT TO A FUNCTION :: START
                var C_longitude = 0;
                var C_name = 0;
                var C_idgps_unit = 0;
                var C_serial = 0;
                var C_speed= 0;
                var C_notes= 0;
                var C_dt = 0;
                var C_time = 0;
                var C_odometer = 0;

                initialize(C_longitude,C_name,C_idgps_unit, C_serial,C_speed, C_notes, C_dt, C_time, C_odometer);
                ///PARSE VALUES AND SUBMIT TO A FUNCTION :: END
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I need to parse the json reponce into values

Comment: What library are you using to parse the JSON response?

Comment: I don't know; not a JS expert here :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `JSON.parse(data)` only gets the associative array in the JSON response, you should be able to get the values in the JSON data like so:

```
var i = 1;
var C_longitude = jsonData[i]["lon"];
var C_name = jsonData[i]["name"];
```

Assuming that the first empty array is not removed by JSON.parse(), i = 1 would get the first batch of data and i = 2 would get the second.

The parsed JSON behaves the same way as if it was defined in JavaScript

Comment: jsonData ? how about where there is multiple `jsonData["name"];` in the array?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see that this was the case. I've updated my answer.

Comment: that was the issue; I was testing on the element-0 and it was unidentified all the time

Comment: An empty array (`[]`) is stored at `jsonData[0]`, that's why everything in jsonData[0] is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `dataType: "json"` in the ajax settings it will return you a json object than you don't need to parse it again. So this would look like:

```
function getCheckedUnits() {
    jQuery(function($) {    
        $.ajax( {           
            url : "json.php?action=get",
            type : "GET",
            dataType: "json"
            success : function(data) {

            }
        });
    });
}
```

However you could also use your own option but than just use the parseJSON function so `var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: how do I get to each variable from json (data) ?

Comment: just like
    `$.each(data, function(key, value){ alert(value); });`